# SQLServer grant Create Procedure is not working

Tags: sql-server

When I tried to "grant create procedure" using the following statement, it did not give any errors. But it did not grant the create procedure permission to the user. What else should I try to grant the Create Procedure permission for a user?

```
grant alter on schema::dbo to [username];

grant create procedure to [username];
```

Comment: Could it be that you were connected to a database like `master` when you granted the permissions and the user is trying to create the procedure on a different database?

Comment: In any case, that's a dangerously wrong configuration.  `username` can now has virtually full control of the dbo schema because of ownership chains.

Answer (score -3):

by granting ALTER to the schema you already gave the user the permission to create stored procedures, that is general permission.